# Having troubles with a List<Color>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, colors, seed

I have a model with a `List<System.Drawing.Color>`, as I mentioned, which comes to use in the `Seed()` like this:

```
    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        var somethings = new List<Something>
        {
            new Something
            {
                Name="blah blah", Colors= { Color.Black, Color.Red }
            }
        };
    }
```

And as long as I have the `Colors` over there like that, I always recieve
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at line `var somethings = new List<Something>`.

When I remove the `Colors`, it goes away and everything works perfectly, what causes this and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

*EDIT:*

**`Something`'s model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MVCApplication7
{
    public class Something
    {
        public int SomethingID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Color> Colors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    ........
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Somethings.ToList());
    }
```

**View:** (I'm sure it's irrelavent because the debugger shows the `Colors` is empty.

```
        @foreach (var itemColor in item.Colors)
        {
            Html.Raw(itemColor.ToString());
        }
```

**Global.asax**

```
    .........
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new DatabaseInitializer());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are your `Something` constructor is returning without setting the `Colors` property to an empty list. Your collection initializer is just calling `Colors.Add(Color.Black)` and then `Colors.Add(Color.Red)` - that's not going to work if the `Colors` property is returning a null reference.

*Either* set it to an empty list to start with (e.g. in the constructor) *or* create a new list and set the property itself:

```
new Something
{
    Name = "blah blah",
    Colors = new List<Color> { Color.Black, Color.Red }
}
```

It's important that you understand the difference between the above code and your original. Your code is currently equivalent to (within the `List<Something>` collection initializer):

```
Something tmp = new Something();
tmp.Name = "blah blah";
tmp.Colors.Add(Color.Black);
tmp.Colors.Add(Color.Red);
// Now add tmp to the list we're building.
```

My code above is equivalent to:

```
Something tmp = new Something();
tmp.Name = "blah blah";
List<Color> tmp2 = new List<Color>();
tmp2.Add(Color.Black);
tmp2.Add(Color.Red);
tmp.Colors = tmp2;
// Now add tmp to the list we're building
```

See the difference?

Comment: Thanks for answering, it doesn't give me the problem at that point anymore, although, when I test it, and try to display for example the first color, I get that same error message. and so of course, the debugger shows that the "Colors" property is null. if you guys need any more code, just let me know which, getting really confusing for me.

Comment: @Ken: Please show a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem if you can. We have no idea how you're using the object.

Comment: Well, the initializer is good, i did as you said (`Colors = new List<Color> { Color.Black, Color.Red }
`), and when I try to write in the view for example inside the foreach loop `@item.Colors[0]` to get the first color, it gives me on that line the same error as before: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` the debugger shows that the `Colors` propety for the foreach's "item" is null.

Comment: @Ken: How are you passing the value to the view? It sounds like that may well be where things are going wrong. What does the debugger show immediately after you've created the object? If it's *got* the colours there, and hasn't got them later, you need to work out at what point they're going missing.

Comment: I'm passing them to the view inside the foreach `item in Model` and just write `item.Colors[0]` for example. after doing what Zero21xxx in the other answer recommanded, I do not recieve this message anymore, the list is not null, but it is empty. when I try to run the code it says that the index is out of range. so I checked the debugger, it had the `Colors` with `Count` of 0. just an empty list. I'm not sure if that's the info you asked for, if it's not please specify what you need in order to help me. Thanks

Comment: @Ken: An empty list is surprising... What happens if you look at the object just after you've constructed it?

Comment: Right after I've constructed it, it does have the colors! it's like it's not adding and saving ONLY the `Colors` inside the context! the `Name` gets there without ever doing any problem. do you want me to post code of something?

Comment: @Ken: Well it's not clear to me how the object is being passed around. You've *shown* a void method which just populates a local variable - obviously that's not going to do anything... how does your real code pass the object from the Seed method to other code?

Comment: Well, I'm just learning these stuff, but I think it passes it through Global.asax in `Application_Start`: `Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new DatabaseInitializer());`

Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Ken: Well you haven't shown where that's being used... please try to show *all* the relevant code in your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4583/discussion-between-ken-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: Updated the question (first post)

Comment: @Ken: You realize your `Seed` method still isn't *doing* anything, right? It's creating a new object which is then completely ignored.

Comment: I could predict me being stupid, so sorry. but I actually don't realize it doesn't do anything. What I understood is that in the Global.asax when I use `Database.SetInitializer` it does load it (and not ignoring it). could you please explain why is it ignored and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Ken: You're declaring a local variable, and initializing it by creating an object. But you're not *doing* anything with that object, as far as we can see. In particular, you're completely ignoring the `context` parameter - I'm not familiar with MVC, but surely you should be *using* `context` somehow? Or at least doing *something* with the list you've just created? Just creating a collection won't have any visible side-effects otherwise... do you have an example of how this (`Seed`) is normally used?

Comment: Yes, in www.asp.net I followed a few guides, but it's the same (although I'll check again just to make sure). I came to your understanding aswell, so I figured that `<DatabaseContext>` part at the `SetInitializer` will do so. anyways I'll check, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor for your Something object, make sure you are instantiating a new object Colors. My guess is that's your problem. You didn't post much code to work with.

Something like this:

```
public Something()
{
     this.Colors = new List<Color>();
}
```

This way you'll always have a valid list object within the Something object.

Ok change your model code to be like this:

```
namespace MVCApplication7
{
    public class Something
    {
        public int SomethingID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Color> Colors { get; set; }
        public Something()
        {
            this.Colors = new List<Color>(); 
        }
    }
}
```

This will instantiate a new list of colors every time you create a new something object and will prevent the object reference error.

*UPDATE*
Ok with what I have listed above as your model, here is your solution to the original question:

```
var list = new List<Something>()
{
   new Something(){SomethingID = 1,Name="John", Colors = {Color.Red,Color.Black}},
   new Something(){SomethingID = 2,Name="George", Colors = {Color.Bisque,Color.Blue}},
   new Something(){SomethingID = 3,Name="Chris", Colors ={Color.Khaki,Color.Cornsilk}}
};
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    foreach (var color in item.Colors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(color.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

You can see that each Something object has it's own unique list of Colors.
Please mark this as the answer if this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm still having a problem which I wrote in Jon Skeet's answer, if you could help me with that it will be great. thanks.

Comment: Post the code of your Something object. Then we can see what we're really dealing with.

Comment: If you mean the model, it has only these 3 propeties: `int SomethingID`, `string Name`, `List<Color> Colors`.

Comment: Edited the question (first post)

Comment: I can't have it outside of the class, so I'm sure you mean to include this under the properties. now it's not null, but it's an empty list of List<Color> (and of course I do have colors in it)

Comment: This is how it was, so it didn't solve the problem. the colors are still empty. any idea how to solve? this problem's getting a bit frustrating.

Comment: According to you, the issue you were having was the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." If you changed your model to the updated one then the code I posted solves that issue. What else are you having problems with?

Comment: As I mentioned in the first comment to your answer, the problem is in the view, not in the model. when I try to make the view show the values of `Colors`, it's empty.

P.S I think it would help if you'd explain to me how come I had to use that constructor in `Colors` and in `Name` for example, I didn't. I didn't quite get it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4580/discussion-between-zero21xxx-and-ken)

Comment: Change your `Index` function on the controller to do something like this to capture the data `var x = db.Somethings.ToList()` Then you can examine `x` before it's passed to the view. I'm guessing that `Colors` is empty at this point and the issue lies in the database.